# Bootrap Tinymce with a sidebar inside HTML form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tinymce

I am trying to create an HTML form which has a TinyMCE editor placed on a text field.

What I would like to do is have the TinyMCE form use the entire width of the screen but leave some space for a sidebar(will be a simple `ul` with some background color, border etc) in parallel (the sidebar is to be used for displaying information relevant to that text field, thus, it must be in parallel with the field).

I have tried playing with the `col-*-8` and `col-*4` models but doesn't work. Hard coding TinyMCE's width also doesn't make the side bar come in parallel (I am using the `form-group` tag on the input element too).

Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/TgZXL/75/ ( I have stripped out all the other tinymce options like width/height and css)

Comment: Paste your code, or better try to create a jsfiddle. Otherwise this question is going to get closed.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle with all the params I think might be relevant. Hope that's okay!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TgZXL/145/